# Where do i put the declarations of my DLL? + how to use it in onther language [C]

Tags: c, dll

1) Lets say I create this DLL called MyDLL in c.
I have 2 files, 1 is MyDLL.c and the 2nd is MyDLL.h, than I compile the code
and get MyDLL.a and MyDLL.dll.
I know how i can use this dll in a new C project, I just include my MyDLL.h and give the
linker the path for my MyDLL.a
now lets say that I dont have the MyDLL.h, than i need to call `LoadLibrary()` but all the function's prototypes and all the typdefs MACROs and structs in the MyDLL.h, so how the program will know all this declarations?
or lets say I want to use the DLL in C# project or JAVA project? i cant include MyDLL.h..

2) If I have a function in the dll that get pointers as parametrs(`void *`, `int *` etc..), how can I send pointers as parameters if I dont have pointer in C# and JAVA or any other language?
Or if the function get struct for parameter? Or even a pointer to function?

Answer (score 1):

Most languages you mention define their own [foreign function interface (FFI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) which is a mechanism for calling code written in other languages. FFI for Java is called [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), and for C# - [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but i see that they need to write the function prototype in the code, but when i send the dll to people they dont know the functions prototypes

Comment: You should provide function signatures as a part of documentation. Alternatively, they can use a utility such as dumpbin or Dependency Walker to see the functions.

Comment: What is the .lib file and .def file?